# Retrieving ember fixture model via "needs"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Doing a basic update to an Ember Fixture record using the new "needs" helper instead of the old "controllerFor". Here is a distilled version of my code:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    utensil: DS.belongsTo('App.Utensil')
});

App.Utensil = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
}); 

App.Item.FIXTURES = [
{id: 0, utensil: 2},
{id: 1, utensil: 1}
];

App.Utensil.FIXTURES = [
{id: 0, name: 'test1'},
{id: 1, name: 'test2'},
{id: 2, name: 'test3'},
{id: 3, name: 'test4'}
];

App.UtensilController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
needs: ["item"],
setUtensil: function(utensil) {
    var item_controller = this.get('controllers.item');
    item_controller.get('model').set('utensil', utensil);           
}
});
```

It seems that the item model is coming back empty. Is this is a fixture limitation or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you show your `ItemController` that you are referencing with `needs` and also how your fixtures for this model do look like?

Comment: ItemController is empty. Should it not be?

Comment: Updated original post to show fixtures.

Comment: I can't see anything out of the ordinary here. If you post a jsbin it would be easier to debug.